# Textbox issue regarding "<>" input

Tags: asp.net

in the textbox when we pass the text within "< >" bracket then it shows the error like 
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (grouplink$txtAddPerson="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it for a single page;

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Or using the web.config for all pages

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You might want to HtmlEncode your input to keep you safe from Scriptinserts

Comment: where we put it in web.config file

Comment: within the system.web section but I'd recommend you'd take Kay's advise.. don't go "system-wide" with this...

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature in asp.net. This is to prevent hacking from the textbox/area. 
The hacker can enter HTML/Script tags inside the textbox and pass to server and get/destroy any data..

You can avoid this feature by disabling through web.config; but I suggest to leave it as it is, as it would be vulnerable to attacks.

**EDIT:**

Please visit for more clarity:
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Allow-HTML-Tags.aspx

Don't make change in web.config as all the pages will be vulnerable. Suggested way is to use it in the Page directive as specified in the link.

Comment: but i have need to remove it. it is requirement of our project.
how can i remove it throug web.config.